# Do you produce more sperm after 1 week of abstinence vs 1 year of abstinence

Tags: human-biology

**Question:** I was wondering if the amount of sperm increase with the amount of abstinence?

**Side questions:**

- Is their a max amount of sperm?
- What happens with the excess amount?

Comment: [Wet dreams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nocturnal_emission) happen, of course.

Comment: Orgasm does not necessary involve ejaculation in those wet dreams.

Comment: I have read after 8 days of abstinence an significant increase is noticed in the amount of sperm and the amount of little soldiers.

Comment: Excess/old sperm is broken down (by phages?) and is re absorbed in the body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an increase by abstinence.

> The within-subject variability of the semen sperm count (n), volume
>   (v) and the total number of spermatozoa (N) was studied on 220
>   ejaculates from 36 normal subjects after an abstinence of 7 days or
>   less.
>
> The three semen characteristics for a given subject were highly
>   correlated with the length of abstinence: for an increase in
>   abstinence of 1 day there were mean increments of 13 × 106/ml for n,
>   0·4 ml for v, and 87 × 106 for N.

- 1979 - [Within-subject variability of human semen in regard to sperm count, volume, total number of spermatozoa and length of abstinence](http://www.reproduction-online.org/content/57/2/391.short)

> Semen analysis was performed on six men after various sexual
>   abstinence periods (from 2 to 18 days). The variations in semen
>   parameters were analyzed statistically as a function of the duration
>   of abstinence.
>
> Lengthy sexual abstinence was found to affect all semen
>   characteristics. Semen volume and concentration and total sperm count
>   showed significant increases, whereas motility and normal morphology
>   decreased significantly with duration of abstinence. Significant
>   changes in the percentage of normal sperm forms were observed after
>   more than seven days' abstinence.
>
> The study indicates that the influence of long sexual abstinence on
>   semen quality varies with the variable considered. With regard to
>   fertility, a long abstinence period might induce senescence of
>   spermatozoa.

- 1994 - [Effect of long abstinence periods on human sperm quality.](http://europepmc.org/abstract/MED/7820161)

Sperms can die of "old age", as the previous quotes mentioned long abstinence period induces senescence. It is hard to find anything about their lifetime, it is at least 7 days I think.

> For humans, entire process of spermatogenesis takes 74 days. Including
>   the transport on ductal system, it takes 3 months. Testes produce 200
>   to 300 million spermatozoa daily.

- according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spermatogenesis)

So there is a constant rate of sperm production.

I think the following differential equation can describe the change of the sperm count:

$$ \dot{x} = μ - Dx $$

where

- x is the sperm count
- μ is the production rate regulated by testosteron (about 250 million per day)
- D is the death rate which depends on the age of the population (depends on the lifetime, production rate, elapsed time)

So there will be a maximum amount by abstinence. By that amount

$$ μ = Dx $$

so

$$ x_{max} = μ /D $$